# Does disabling Siri replace it with Voice Control in IOS 7+

Tags: ios, siri

If you disable Siri in general, will holding the home button (when phone is locked) activate the old Voice Control instead?

Comment: This site works better if there is just one question at once. I've edited your question accordingly, feel free to ask a new question for the second bart. Also what prevents you from testing this yourself?

Comment: I don't have an iphone yet, therefore my question.. only experience with android.. sorry i forgot mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

If you disable Siri, it will then activate Voice Control when you hold the home button. Being on the lock screen or not doesn't make a difference.